# Custom delegate methods in a NSTextView subclass - compiler warnings

Tags: cocoa

Long story short (please stop me if I'm doing this wrong): I want to have an NSTextView accept a custom drag type, and upon receipt of such a drag change the content to match.
To do this, I subclass NSTextView to implement the custom drag type, and (from the subclass) send a message to the NSTextView delegate when done. This works just fine, but I get a familiar compiler warning (though everything works fine):

> Method '-dragReceivedWithTrack:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Some code:

```
@interface LyricTextView : NSTextView {
}

@end

@interface NSObject (CustomDragging)
-(BOOL)dragReceivedWithTrack:(NSDictionary *)track;
@end


@implementation LyricTextView
-(BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSData *data = [[sender draggingPasteboard] dataForType:kMyType];
    NSDictionary *track = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(dragReceivedWithTrack:)]) {
        return ([[self delegate] dragReceivedWithTrack:track]); // gives a warning, but works
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Shouldn't the informal protocol take care of the warning?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared a protocol, you have declared a category on NSObject. You could probably remove its definition without affecting the compiler warning.

Since you have a subclass, you are stuck with the delegate as it is (which is an id ).

To quelch the compiler warning, you should be able to simply cast it to id, like so:

id delegate = (id)[self delegate]
if ((delegate respondsToSelector:...]) {...}

Comment: A category, especially one declared on `NSObject`, is called an informal protocol.

Comment: Sure, you can abuse the categories this way (and it's even in Apple's documentation) but you should really declare your protocols with @protocol / @optional if that's really what you want to do.
Adding a category on NSObject does nothing special for this particular code. The important part is respondsToSelector: